# How to present TeX documents directly from the iPad on a projector?

Tags: presentations, ipad

Now that there are useful authoring environments for TeX documents available on the iPad, I would wish to be able to present their results (e.g., a beamer document) directly from an iPad via the VGA connector to a "physical" beamer (or Television set) instead of using a laptop.

So my question is, are there possibilities and if so which?

My limitation right now is that I have an iPad1; I think the newer hardware can mirror the iPad screen. However, even for newer hardware app-based video output might be preferable to screen mirroring as this allows the app to suppress option buttons etc on the video screen.

Comment: Is this really a TeX question?  The iPad 1 is limited in the apps that permit mirroring.  See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2793924?start=0&tstart=0 for some discussion. Maybe the folks on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I have iPad2 and use PDFPresenter and GoodReader to mirror PDF files on a VGA projector. Not sure if they work for iPad1.

Comment: If you can find an app on the list [here](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-general-discussions/22454-hdmi-vga-display-apps-first-gen-ipad-no-jailbreak.html) that displays PDF, then you're set to go.

Comment: @AlanMunn I thik it is and it isn't. Are editor question TeX questions, not per se, but if the base intend is related to "using TeX" my guess is that others would be interested in such a question too. And some of the comments could already be made in a helpful answer

Comment: I stumbled upon something bizarre today, maybe it could be of use here: [PDF rendering in Javascript](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)?

Comment: I use GoodNotes for PDF presentation.  It has a very clean interface and annotation tools.  It works very well for beamer presentations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPad 1 supports screen mirroring only for certain apps. For some discussion of this, see

- [iPad 1 VGA connector - no image on external monitor](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2793924?start=0&tstart=0)

That being said, however, it seems that many apps *do* support screen mirroring.  The following list seems to be quite extensive and includes a few apps that can display PDF, which is what you would need to display TeX output.  Pipiro notes in the comments that Goodnotes can also mirror on the iPad 1.

- [HDMI/VGA Display-Apps On First Gen iPad (No Jailbreak)](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-general-discussions/22454-hdmi-vga-display-apps-first-gen-ipad-no-jailbreak.html)

Subsequent iPad models support mirroring for all apps, so you should be able to use your favourite PDF viewer to display PDFs on current versions of the iPad.

Comment: you are only good to go, if your TeX application supports Apple's document exchange interface "Open in ..." for the generated PDFs in that application. I do have TeXWriter and for this one this is the case so it becomes indeed very easy to do a presentation straight from the iPad1. Don't know about texpad but would be interested to learn. Perhaps one should add this kind of info to the answer to help others.

Comment: So maybe I've completely misunderstood the question: is the question whether TeX *authoring* environments support mirroring on the iPad 1? This is a different question from how do you mirror a PDF document on iPad 1.  Any useful TeX authoring environment should have Dropbox support, I would suppose, and so should any good PDF reader.

Comment: well the question was how to have an authoring possibility that allows projection and missing that in a direct way, how to achieve it nevertheless. When I'm going to Japan this fall I would certainly like to a) present some beamer pdf (which I can via GoodReader nicely as I now learned but also b) compile TeX examples and show them straight away (not so easy, or probably not even possible right now). Using dropbox is really just the poor man's solution as it requires internet connectivety. fortunately TeXWriter can open directly pdfs in GoodReader or other apps, which solves a) better.